# Simple Jquery post posting twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Not sure whats going wrong here, I'm getting the response posted back to the page as I would expect based on all of the variables being populated, but a few seconds later it's being overwritten by PHP errors saying expected variables are empty. I've been searching on here for something helpful but nothing usable. Any ideas appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#sendV6DplMail").click(function()
    {
                var message = $("#MessageContent").val();
                var bcc = $("#bcc").val();
                var cc = $("#cc").val();
                var subject = $("#subject").val();
                var packRef = $("#packRef").val();

                alert(packRef + " / " + subject);
                // variables for username and password are being read from credentials.js (include file above)

                $.post("includes/sendMail.php", {message: message, bcc: bcc, cc: cc, subject: subject, packRef: packRef, user: user, password: password}, function(result)
                {
                    $("#v6MailSent").html(result);
                }); 

    });
});
```

Comment: try console.log'ing the vars to check data is actually being apassed

Comment: Hi @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs, The data is being posted and appears in the console log, and I get the results displaying on my page as I expect. Then it seems to post again, the console log is deleted and I get my errors. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do prevent default first
like in documentation of [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)
code sample :

```
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();

$.post("includes/sendMail.php", {message: message, bcc: bcc, cc: cc, subject: subject, packRef: packRef, user: user, password: password}, function(result)
                {
                    $("#v6MailSent").html(result);
                }); 
    });
```

Since you don't prevent the default behaviour of your element named #sendV6DplMail that's why it's happening.

Comment: Hi Kacper, you are correct, and I'm in your debt. I stupidly missed that here, thanks to you now tested and working. Have a great day and I'm grateful for the support.